# Python If then Else style when getting values from Dicts

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

I often struggle with the following if/else syntax and I was hoping some people could give me some of their opinions as to what they think is more clear or if this violates any Pythonisms (I've searched and wasn't able to find anything).

Is one of these better and or right/wrong?

```
value = None
if 'value' in some_dict:
  value = some_dict['value']

some_func(value=value)
```

OR:

```
if 'value' in some_dict:
  value = some_dict['value']
else:
  value = None

some_func(value=value)
```

OR:

```
some_func(value=some_dict.get('value', None))
```

I could see reasons for all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course the last one is the best - described situation is exact case for `dict.get`.

Just a note - second parameter to `get` is superfluous, you can simply write:

```
some_func(value=some_dict.get('value'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks most natural to me:

```
value = some_dict.get('value')
some_func(value=value)
```

Or: the last case. The question was edited while I replied.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dict's `get()` method as in your third example. That use case is exactly what it's there fore.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a matter of style, I would use the last just because it's more succint (and notice you can omit the `None` as it is the default)

btw there's also this:

```
value = some_dict['value'] if 'value' in some_dict else None
```

but that's exactly what `.get()` does

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the [dict.get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method seems to be the more suitable to what you need.

BUT, if you didn't want to launch the method if the value wasn't in the dictionnary, a pythonic way (according to the [EAFP principle](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)) would have been :

```
try:
   some_func(some_dict['value'])
except KeyError:
   pass
```