# Python default values and setting the value based on other variables. To if else or to not.

Tags: python, coding-style, syntax, default-value

At times I have a variable that I want to default to something and if something else is set change it to something else.

The question is. What is preferred? Setting the default value and then changing it if the condition is met or setting the condition only once depending on the initial check with an added else?

Example in code.

```
if x:
    y = '%s-other' % x
else:
    y = 'some_default'
```

The other option would be.

```
y = 'some_default'
if x:
    y = '%s-other' % x
```

This isn't always an argument passed in to a function so kwargs is not something I want to rely on here.

Personally, the second one seems to be a lot more clear to me but what I have yet to find any sort of opinion by anyone on this.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Near identical dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730946/python-if-then-else-style-when-getting-values-from-dicts

Comment: It is a near identical dupe but different, I asked both of them :) I could have consolidated it in to one. Not sure if I can do that now?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
y = '%s-other' % x if x else 'some_default'
```

Answer (score 4):

As Rob pointed out,

```
y = '%s-other' % x if x else 'some_default'
```

is a very common construct across various language

Python provides some more alternatives and the choice depends on the User

```
y = ['some_default','%s-other'][x!=None]
```

If you are dealing with dictionary, it already has two options

1. Use setdefault like `x.setdefault(some_key,some_default)=other`
2. Use collections.defaultdict

The other's you posted are also valid but not very pythonic but yet you will encounter lot of code with your quoted style.

To me, as long as a program is readable, efficient, we should not be too bogged down to make some contruct pythonic which often deviates the focus.

Comment: +1 for the alternatives, although `bool(x)` may be better than `x!=None` in the array indexing option.

Comment: 1. Rob's variant is better than `[if_false, if_true][cond]`. If you still use it then `None` is a singleton in Python so it should be `x is not None` instead of `x != None`. 2. `y = x.setdefault(some_key, 'some_default')`, otherwise it `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`.

Answer (score 0):

More sugar to other answers:

```
y = x and '%s-other' % x or 'some_default'
```

But this one may scare people so I'd recomend to use Rob's one :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers deal with the more general `if-elif-else` case.

When there's only one condition the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions) is probably the best way to go, as other answers pointed out:

```
option = 42 if condition else 'default'
```

But if there are two or more conditions it becomes cumbersome. But the best option there may depend if it is a true default:

```
option = 'default'
if condition1:
    option = 1
elif condition2:
    option = 2
```

or simply another case:

```
if z > 0:
    sign = 'positive'
elif z < 0:
    sign = 'negative'
else:
    sign = 'null'
```